# Memory keeps on growing publishing images via pyZMQ publisher socket

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, messagebroker, pyzmq

I am trying to code a publisher that takes images from a simulation through APIs and publish them through a tcp socket, so that multiple processes -not necessarily on the same machine- can access the images subscribing to the topic. Everything seems to work, since I can see the streamed images via the subscriber. The only issue is that the memory associated with the publisher keeps on growing indefinitely, both with the subscriber active and without.
Here is how the publisher is used:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556")
topic = "img_rgba"
time.sleep(2)
while(1):
    [...]   
    socket.send_string(topic, zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send_pyobj(image)
```

Do you have any clue?

Thanks a lot, 
Marco